# How do I call addConstraint from an NSApplicationDelegate in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have managed to successfully add constraints programatically in a Custom View class (sub-class of NSView) using the following code:

```
[self addConstraint:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.myObject
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                 toItem:self
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                             multiplier:1
                               constant:0]];
```

But now I want to do something similar from the App Delegate (sub-class of NSApplicationDelegate).
I am unsure of which object to add the constraint to.

Trying to call it the same way, results in a compilation error

```
[self addConstraint:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.backgroundBox
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                 toItem:self
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                             multiplier:1
                               constant:0]];
```

I have tried replacing the object I am adding the constraint to (and the object in the "toItem" parameter) self.view (the view holding the backgroundBox object), [self.window contentView] and even self.backgroundBox.superview, but they either won't compile or don't seem to have any effect.

Can anyone advise on the correct way to do this?
I just want to be able to centre backgroundBox vertically within the view
(self.view is the top level view in the nib file linked to the app delegate)
(self.backgroundBox is a box within self.view)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Note: I would much prefer to do this programatically rather than having to use IB to add constraints)

Using Xcode5 with OSX 10.9.3

Comment: How does `self addConstraint` even make sense for an application delegate?

Comment: It doesn't, which explains the error when I did the original copy-paste.
So I'm now trying to find the correct NSView to add it to, which I had hoped would be the content view of self.window (self being the app delegate)

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning what the goal of this is.  I have an NSBox that I want to fill the entire contents of a window (so I don't have to update the size of the box if the size of the window changes) - so I want to set the width and height to that of the window and centre it.